# How to create a simple Chat App in android

Tags: android, asmack

I wanna create a simple chat app in android but really I don't how to start 
I really searched in google but really I didn't find any helpful link or code

so guys please I need your help how Can I start any video link or any simple code

Comment: Please take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/tour. We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: THanks man for your comment but don't do my homework for me 
just tell me how I can start  just this 
thanks again you're right

Comment: Also note that there are many FOSS XMPP Clients for Android. Have a look at their source and learn from it. After all, that's the spirit of open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have some experience in Java I can recommend this book:

> Professional Android 4 Application Development (Wrox)

It really helped me to get started with Android development. Otherwise the best start is probably a quick introduction to Java. In German there's also a book called Java for Android, not sure if it exists in English, too.

Also for inspiration you can have a look at this:

> https://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/

Comment: THanks Dan am really soooo good in android but really it's too new for me to create chat app 
what you say about this example
http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Building-a-Chat-Application
really it's too good for me to create something like this 
but I got some error and I cant handle it

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question.

Comment: what you say about using Instant messaging (IM) communication 
asmack and GoogleTalk

Comment: I don't have any experience in writing a chat message, sorry.

Comment: No Thanks Dan your commment so helpfulllllllllll thanks 
am really appreciate :)